# 2004 Buick Lesabre

Tags: cel

I have a 2004 Buick Lesabre. The check engine light came on so I had the code read. It was P0442. The gas cap was just sitting there so I tightened it. This has been a couple of weeks ago and the light is still on. Does this mean there is something else wrong or do I have to take it somewhere to have the light reset?

Comment: its worth a shot to try a reset.  Your local auto store can do that for you for free.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and see is it comes back on.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take the battery loose for a few minutes and that will reset it but you got to reprogram your radio stations in clock all over again that's the only sucky part about it

Answer (score 0):

Once the check engine light comes on it won't go away even if the problem is fixed, you have to get it cleared. Really the only way to tell if it's fixed is to clear the code and then see if it re-occurs. You should get it reset because at the moment you wouldn't know if another fault occurred.